# Center a Wordpress Menu

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone help me center this menu in Wordpress? Currently it stays to the right

```
#primary_menu{position:absolute;top:14px;right:0;text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);}
.jqueryslidemenu{position:relative;z-index:2000;line-height:20px;letter-spacing:.2px;text-transform:uppercase;}
.jqueryslidemenu a{display:block;padding:5px;}
.jqueryslidemenu a:hover{color:#fff;text-decoration:none;}
.jqueryslidemenu ul{margin:0;padding:0;list-style-type:none;float:right;}
.jqueryslidemenu li{padding:5px 10px;float:left;list-style:none;height:45px;position:relative;display:inline;margin:0;}
.jqueryslidemenu ul ul{width:212px;position:absolute;top:20px;padding:4px;margin-left:4px;margin-right:4px;display:block;visibility:hidden;}
.jqueryslidemenu li li{display:list-item;float:none;padding:1px;height:auto;}
.jqueryslidemenu li li a{width:200px;margin:0;height:100%;padding:6px 9px;}
.jqueryslidemenu ul ul ul{margin-top:-5px;z-index:2001;}
.jqueryslidemenu li small{display:none;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the revised CSS markup to have your menu centered.

```
#primary_menu{text-align:center;text-shadow:0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5)}
.jqueryslidemenu{z-index:2000;line-height:20px;letter-spacing:.2px;text-transform:uppercase}
.jqueryslidemenu ul{padding:0;list-style-type:none}
.jqueryslidemenu li{padding:5px 10px;list-style:none;height:45px;display:inline-block}
.jqueryslidemenu ul ul{width:212px;position:absolute;top:20px;padding:4px;margin-left:4px;margin-right:4px;display:block;visibility:hidden}
.jqueryslidemenu li li{display:list-item;float:none;padding:1px;height:auto}
.jqueryslidemenu li li a{width:200px;margin:0;height:100%;padding:6px 9px}
.jqueryslidemenu ul ul ul{margin-top:-5px;z-index:2001}
.jqueryslidemenu li small{display:none}
.jqueryslidemenu a{display:block;padding:5px}
.jqueryslidemenu a:hover{color:#fff;text-decoration:none}
```

And here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fg4Pj/